# Unable to import ChannelSftp.LsEntry from Jsch when I use it in Scala code, why?

Tags: scala, sftp, jsch

So in my scala class, I had to use the Jsch(JAVA) library to do SFTP work. But for some reason, it is unable to import:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry
```

Any idea why this would be? LsEntry is a nested class of ChannelSftp.

http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html

```
package services.impl

import java.nio.file.Path

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry
import services.InputService

class InputServiceImpl extends InputService[List[ChannelSftp.LsEntry]] {

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out.

In scala, to reference an nested class, you use the following syntax:

```
ChannelSftp#LsEntry
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how this works?  If possible please Include some source code that would help me understand how you were able to access the LsEntry.

Comment: havent touch scala in a while. but iirc, that is how scala access the innner classes

Comment: I figured it out: val lsEntry = file.asInstanceOf[ChannelSftp#LsEntry]